# Buildkit - amp test failed - /root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/root/' is executable'

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I am trying to setup buildkit in my new Debian machine. I installed all the required packaged, ran `civi-download-tools` and `amp config` with correct credentials and included `Include /root/.amp/apache.d/*.con` in *apache2.conf* file. On restarting apache it gave me error saying there was no *.conf file to be included in `/root/.amp/apache.d`. I checked the directory; **it was empty.**

However, I copied `localhost-7979.conf` from my previous buildkit setup on another machine and placed inside `/root/.amp/apache.d` folder and restarted apache. On running `amp test` it gave me following error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://localhost:7979/index.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden  in phar:///opt/buildkit/bin/amp/src/Amp/Command/TestCommand.php on line 163
```

I checked `localhost-7979-error.log` inside `root/.amp/log`. Following line was there.

```
'/root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/root/' is executable'
```

Strange. There isn't even any *.htaccess* file inside `/root`.
I tried every solution I could find on CiviCRM StackExchange and Forums but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was performing all actions as a root. That was probably the reason no .conf file was generated in */root/.amp/apache.d/*. I switched to a non-root user with sudo privileges and it worked smoothly.